# Align 'read more' button under article - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, alignment

I am trying to align the read more button straight, centered under the article but I am not able to do it. It's not changing the position at all. Can someone help me? Here's the CSS

```
.more-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-right: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #333333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any alignment you try to on non-blocking elements will not work. See in your code you have, ***display: inline-block;*** Change it to **display: block;** then apply any alignment and it will work.

If you cannot change original code, then add in your custom css section this code:

```
.more-link {
 display: block !important;
}
```